# QtCreator how to install "Uncrustify" C++ Beautifer?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

QtCreator (3.0.1, Ubuntu 14.04 LTS) allows the installation of C++ code Beautifier "Uncrustify", for reformatting existing code.  This all looks simple from instructions http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-beautifier.html, but I am stuck on basic inability to install.

I have downloaded, compiled and installed the latest `uncrustify-0.61`.  This creates the executable etc. fine, and installs in system area.

The instructions then state:

> Select Help > About Plugins > C++ > Beautifier to enable the plugin.

Well, there is no "Beautifier" plugin showing under C++.  Hardly surprising, since building/installing "Uncrustify" does not do anything to "tell" Qt Creator it is there/available.  How do you get Qt Creator to know the plugin is available to Load?

In have searched everywhere on the web for help.  My *guess* is that in directory `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qtcreator/plugins/QtProject` there needs to be a file like `Uncrustify.pluginspec` (plus anything else), but there is no mention of this.  I have scoured the web for anything to show how to actually install and make it work, but found nothing more than the instructions above, which do not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, turns out this is an issue for the C++ Beautifier plugin in general rather than "Uncrustify" in particular, and a Qt Creator version-too-old.

The files required are `Beautifier.pluginspec` and `libBeautifier.so`.

Although I was being directed to the "Beautifier" Help from the Qt Creator Version **3.0.1** which gets installed from the Ubuntu **14.04 LTS** Software Centre, Beautifier support was only introduced at Qt Creator **3.1** --- though that is hard to discover from web searching.

So at Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, either Beautifier is simply not available by default, or you can go replace the shipped 3.0.1 Qt Creator with an Open Source 3.1+, or maybe just pick those 2 files out of a 3.1 distribution/installation and see if they work OK under 3.0.1.